# Issue connecting to SQL Server with 32 bit application set to true

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am running a web application on IIS8 and need to set the application pool to run with 32 bit. When I set 'Enable 32 bit application' to true I can no longer connect to SQL Server 2012.

From my research it appears this has to do with my connection string set for 64 bit. I cannot find any examples of how to resolve this. Do I need to add something to my connection string? Do I need to find a different dll for SQL Server in my application?

I would really appreciate any help in resolving this.

Thanks
Charles

Comment: I think first question would be - why do you want to go into 32 bit mode?

Comment: Please post your code so we can see how you are connecting. Also the connection string (excluding any sensitive info).

Comment: I am using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and it will not work under 64bit.  My connection string is:  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaMAT.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>  Thanks